# vscode combining two fonts(Dank Mono for general + Fira Code ligatures)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just installed the font Dank Mono, which is great but it lacks some ligature, like `<=` or `>=`.
Is there a way to use Dank Mono for letters or numbers, and Fira Code as "back-up" to enable ligatures unavailable with Dank Mono ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this plugin:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css

But it will take a lot of work on your part to set it up. This allows you to inject arbitrary CSS. You may have an easier time simply patching your Dank Mono font to use Fira Code's ligatures.